# IAP items not showing using the Xamarin IAP nuget package

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I have two IAPs set up on for my iOS app on iTunes Connect. All of the information is in there and they marry up to what I have set for Android. On iTunes, they are set as non-renewing subscriptions (mainly as this is what the review said they should be). There are no errors shown on the IAP screen and have been submitted for review (this makes no difference, the ones I had there previously didn't show either)

I'm using the Xamarin In App Purchase nuget package to get this working. When I run the app on Android, the packages show correctly. When I run the same code on iOS, nothing is showing.

I have a user set on the sandbox and have followed the instructions on the iTunes website on logging out of the store, but I'm seeing nothing - it's not even asking me to log into the store.

My code for interrogating the store is this

```
async Task<List<InAppBillingProduct>> GetItems()
    {
        var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
        try
        {

            var productIds = new string[] { "monthly_renewals", "yearly_subscriptions" };
            //You must connect
            var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();

            if (!connected)
            {
                //Couldn't connect
                return new List<InAppBillingProduct>();
            }

            //check purchases

            var items = await billing.GetProductInfoAsync(ItemType.Subscription, productIds);
            return items.ToList();
        }
        catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException)
        {
            return new List<InAppBillingProduct>();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new List<InAppBillingProduct>();
        }
        finally
        {
            await billing.DisconnectAsync();
        }
    }
```

It makes no difference if I set the ItemType to Subscription or InAppPurchase. All of the licences on iTunesConnect are correct, IAP is set to work in the provisioning profile too.

Given the store isn't asking for a login for the sandbox user, I'm wondering if something else needs to be done - I just don't know what.

Comment: Ensure your app has a valid App ID (not a wildcard with an asterisk * in it) and has In App Purchasing enabled.

Comment: Both of these are fine which is why it's baffling me